# Symmetry arguments in Gauss law and Superposition

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, superposition, linear-systems

Right now I am working on electrostatics. One of the techniques used is to use coulombs law and superposition in a situation where one can sum the point charges and corresponding fields to get the total field. I am having trouble understanding how the E field can be completely described by charge only. Charge is a number and E is a 3-vector at a certain point in space. The dimension of charge is 1 and the dimension of E is 3. Does that mean the E field really only has 1 degree of freedom? ( 2 degrees of freedom for each point charge) That is the E field only depends on distance. For a set of charges (p1,p2,...), the superposition principle states that E is a function of <strike>(r1,r2,...)</strike> (p1,p2,r1,r2...). Is there a way to show from Gauss's law and superposition **(sources are independent)** the empirical fact of Coulombs law?
del * E = p/e ,E1 + E2 = E(p1/e + p2/e) => <strike>E(r1,r2)</strike> E(p1,p2,r1,r2). **Coulombs Law is an axiom or http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesph.html#c1?**

In class we used a del*E = p/e and "symmetry" to derive Coulombs law. What is this symmetry? Is this symmetry important for a point charge and electrostatics as a whole? Basically because rotating the charge in the theta or phi direction does not change the point charge, the field (for a point charge). Does this imply that E must point in the r direction and only depend on r? p(r,theta,phi) where dp/dtheta = 0 and dp/dphi = 0 => E(r)r direction? How?  [Gauss' Law and Symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/404947/gauss-law-and-symmetry)

Comment: To find the electric field due to a charged particle you would need to know both the charge and the location of the particle.

Comment: The electric field is used to describe the force on a test charge q: $\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{E}$. So for a point charge, the field is given by $\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{F}/q$, where $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ are evaluated at the position of the test charge, given the validty of Coulombs Law. No you cannot derive Coulombs Law from Gauss' Law, since Gauss' Law is derived from Coulombs Law.

Comment: So E would be a function of (p1,r1,p2,r2) . B Brekke?

Comment: E has two degrees of freedom for each point charge?

Comment: @Samuel the electric field exists regardless of the existance of the test charge , the field is more fundamental than the force.

Comment: @JunSeo-He Yes I am aware of that, but I don't think that OP is on that level yet where he would need more information than that.

Comment: @dfdf No, E is completely determined by the point charge. If you have multiple point charges, the total electric field is the sum of the electric fields generated by the individual point charges (as you know already).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450680/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Samuel You are correct from an historical/pedagogical point of view.  But from a logical point of view, that is a set of axioms and logical propositions,   One could take Gauss' law as the axiom and derive Coulomb's Law.   Doing so is an instructive exercise.

Comment: Superposition comes from the empirical fact that all sources are independent

Comment: @dfdf and that Maxwell's equations are linear

Comment: Please post formulae with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421). This makes it easier for other users to read your post.

Comment: @garyp I mean that would be a nice vector calculus exercise, but beyond that I don't think you will gain more intuition from that exercise, when you only switch from Coulomb  to Gauss being axiomatic. When arguing which of them is more fundamental, I would agree that that would be Gauss' Law. But in classical electrodynamics, it doesn't add to the understanding, because the choice is arbitrary.